# Using Ag-Grid Enterprise license getting a 'ag-grid: Looking for component [agSetColumnFilter] but it wasn't found." error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I've been using Ag-Grid's Enterprise feature "**agSetColumnFilter**" for months with no problem.

I'm using the following versions:

```
    "ag-grid": "^17.1.1",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^17.1.1",
    "ag-grid-react": "^17.1.0",
```

After a bit of refactoring, I'm starting to get this error after just clicking on the filter menu:

```
ag-grid: Looking for component [agSetColumnFilter] but it wasn't found.
Array.concat.ComponentProvider.retrieve @ componentProvider.js?6ebb:209
Array.concat.ComponentResolver.resolveByName @ componentResolver.js?1587:159
Array.concat.ComponentResolver.getComponentToUse @ componentResolver.js?1587:155
Array.concat.ComponentResolver.newAgGridComponent @ componentResolver.js?1587:271
Array.concat.ComponentResolver.createAgGridComponent @ componentResolver.js?1587:236
Array.concat.FilterManager.createFilterInstance @ filterManager.js?d1c0:376
Array.concat.FilterManager.createFilterWrapper @ filterManager.js?d1c0:393
Array.concat.FilterManager.getOrCreateFilterWrapper @ filterManager.js?d1c0:343
Array.concat.StandardMenuFactory.showPopup @ standardMenu.js?505d:52
Array.concat.StandardMenuFactory.showMenuAfterButtonClick @ standardMenu.js?505d:45
Array.concat.HeaderComp.showMenu @ headerComp.js?f669:122
(anonymous) @ headerComp.js?f669:107
componentResolver.js?1587:274 Error creating component filter=>agTextColumnFilter
Array.concat.ComponentResolver.newAgGridComponent @ componentResolver.js?1587:274
Array.concat.ComponentResolver.createAgGridComponent @ componentResolver.js?1587:236
Array.concat.FilterManager.createFilterInstance @ filterManager.js?d1c0:376
Array.concat.FilterManager.createFilterWrapper @ filterManager.js?d1c0:393
Array.concat.FilterManager.getOrCreateFilterWrapper @ filterManager.js?d1c0:343
Array.concat.StandardMenuFactory.showPopup @ standardMenu.js?505d:52
Array.concat.StandardMenuFactory.showMenuAfterButtonClick @ standardMenu.js?505d:45
Array.concat.HeaderComp.showMenu @ headerComp.js?f669:122
(anonymous) @ headerComp.js?f669:107
filterManager.js?d1c0:401 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null
    at FilterManager.Array.concat.FilterManager.putIntoGui (filterManager.js?d1c0:401)
    at FilterManager.Array.concat.FilterManager.createFilterWrapper (filterManager.js?d1c0:394)
    at FilterManager.Array.concat.FilterManager.getOrCreateFilterWrapper (filterManager.js?d1c0:343)
    at StandardMenuFactory.Array.concat.StandardMenuFactory.showPopup (standardMenu.js?505d:52)
    at StandardMenuFactory.Array.concat.StandardMenuFactory.showMenuAfterButtonClick (standardMenu.js?505d:45)
    at HeaderComp.Array.concat.HeaderComp.showMenu (headerComp.js?f669:122)
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (headerComp.js?f669:107)
```

The refactoring work I did was to iterate over an array and create React-Bootstrap tab components that render the Ag-grid components when clicked. I place the array of tabs in a `<div>` to be rendered.

For my **row data**, it's an array like so:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  keyword: 'tv',
  projects: [{ id: 1, name: 'Project 1' }, {id: 2, name: 'Project 2' }]
},
{
  id: 2,
  keyword: 'sofa',
  projects: [{ id: 3, name: 'Project 3' }]
}]
```

My **column definitions** are returned from a function like this: (`lookup` is a hash where my filter options are stored, I iterate over the values and produce an array of strings to give to `filterParams.values`:

```
function createColumnDefs = (lookup) => ([
{
  field: 'projects',
  headerName: 'Projects',
  filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
  cellRenderer: 'ListRenderer',
  cellRendererParams: {
    accessor: 'name'
   },
   filterParams: {
     values: _.get(lookup, 'projects', []).map(project => project.name),
     debounceMs: 200
  }
},
{
  field: 'keyword',
  headerName: 'Keyword',
  filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
  sort: 'asc',
  filterParams: {
    debounceMs: 200
  },
  pinned: 'left',
  minWidth: 250
}
]);
```

Everything works fine including displaying rows, row selection, sorting, text filtering, the infinite scroll. ONLY when I click on the filter hamburger menu in the column header does it give the above error.

This filter has worked in the past and since then I have not altered row data structure or my column definitions or filter options.

*************** Screenshots for reference ***************

[image: My row data (an array of objects]
[image: Column Defs that I pass into Ag-grid]

[image: error printed in Chrome inspector]

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by

- running `npm i @ag-grid-enterprise/set-filter`,
- importing the module in the component that used the set filter: `import { SetFilterModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/set-filter';`
- adding `SetFilterModule` to grid modules array:

  `gridModules = [ClientSideRowModelModule, RowGroupingModule, MenuModule, SetFilterModule];`
- and of course binding gridModules to the grid (which I had from before): `<ag-grid-angular... [modules]="gridModules"></ag-grid-angular>`

I got this solution from inspecting the code in the first example on https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-set/

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and was able to resolve by removing "filter: true" from my column definitions. I see that you're defining specific types of filters in your definitions, you might try removing it and seeing if ag-grid recognizes the types of filters it needs. If that doesn't work, you might try changing those filters to custom filters instead. Hope that helps!